# Activity not opening when clicking menu item

Tags: java, android

I am trying to tap on the "logout" option whose id is logout but nothing happens. Below is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.requestpayment,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.logout:
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,Logout.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

please help

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `onCreateOptionsMenu` method replace

```
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

by

```
return true;
```

and replace `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` in `onOptionsItemSelected()` by `return true`

Comment: @HarrisonKuria cool! glad to know that! Don't forget to mark this question as answered whenever possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to return true in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and in `onOptionsItemSelected()` after starting the activity.

The correct way would be like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.requestpayment,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.logout:
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,Logout.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you chain a overridden method to its superclass(i.e call `super.someMethod()`), it means you are requesting the superclass to handle the implementation on its own.
You should `return true` here to tell that you successfully inflated the `menu` in this **child** `Activity` OR succesfully handled the `onClick()` event on the **option items**.

---

**NOTE:** Mostly, you need to chain a `superclass` method call, where `superclass` is reponsible for doing some critical stuffs. For eg:

```
public class ChildActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //request superclass to do its critical stuffs
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //continue with your logics here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Restart Android studio. Let me know if that still persists

Comment: "return true;" in "onCreateOptionsMenu" has worked for me. Thanks for your concern, Bless